# Ncurses flickers when using pipes or redirection

Tags: c, input, ncurses, getch

Ncurses flickers when using "unix pipes" and "redirection" for input. That is, it draws fine if I input myself but doesn't when using '|' or '<'.

I thought this might be due to `getch()` ***delay modes***(no delay, half delay and infinite delay). So I explicitly tried setting `nodelay(stdscr, FALSE);` but as obvious, it didn't solve it.

This is the minimal working code :

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Default assumptions */
#define BUFSIZE         100
#define SELINDICATOR    ">>> "
#define MAXITEMS        LINES   /* Decides how many items are shown at a time. By default, it's (number of rows - 1) */

/* Declarations */
static void draw(char **data, short index, short selected);
static void handleInput(short *selected, short index);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char buf[BUFSIZE], **data;
    short index = 0, selected = 1;
    size_t curSize = 0;

    /* Get the entries */
    while(fgets(buf, BUFSIZE, stdin)) {

        if(!(data = realloc(data, (curSize += sizeof(char *))))) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error reallocating memory!\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        if(!(data[index] = malloc(BUFSIZE))) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error reallocating memory!\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        strcpy(data[index], buf);
        index++;
    }

    /* Start nCurses */
    initscr();
    noecho();
    nodelay(stdscr, FALSE); // just tryin' it out if it works

    while(1) {

        draw(data, index, selected);
        handleInput(&selected, index);
    }

    /* Quit nCurses */
    endwin();

    /* Free allocated memories */
    for(short i = 0; i < index; i++)
        free(data[i]);
    free(data);

    return 0;
}

void
draw(char **data, short index, short selected) {

    static short posX = strlen(SELINDICATOR), posY; /* posY doesn't need to be static but it makes no difference and looks cleaner */

        /* Clear old garbage */
        clear();
        posY = 0;

        /* Draw line echoing inputs */
        mvaddch(posY, 0, '>');
        posY++;

        /* Draw the entries */
        for(short i = 0; posY < COLS && i < index; i++) {

            if(posY == selected) {
                mvprintw(posY, 0, SELINDICATOR);
            }

            mvprintw(posY, posX, "%s", data[i]);
            refresh();
            posY++;
        }

        /* Make the output visible */
        refresh();
}

void
handleInput(short *selected, short numOfEntries) {

    int input = getch();

    /* A whole bunch of other stuff........ */

    endwin();
    exit(0);
}
```

Much thanks for your efforts!

Comment: Ncurses is not designed or intended to be used with I/O redirection.  It is built for interacting with a *terminal*, and redirection of its input (normally) creates a situation where its input is *not* from a terminal.  That doesn't necessarily mean that the combination won't work, but it's not surprising that the behavior is non-ideal.  If redirecting your program's input from a pipe or file is something you want or need to support, then you should consider dropping ncurses.

Comment: @John any workarounds while still using ncurses? And btw I am using `fgets()` to get input and that I am pretty sure isn't ncurses specific.

Comment: I suppose "drop redirection instead" is not the solution you're looking for ....

Comment: Try `cat | vi | cat`, does it work? If not, then you probably can't make it work either.

Comment: @SaurabhKr.Yadav, you do use `fgets()` initially, and indeed that is not ncurses-specific, but it also is not relevant as far as I can tell.  Once you start up the GUI, you use ncurses's `getch()` for input.

Comment: My guess would be that it flickers with I/O redirection because in that case, it is pushing out screen refreshes as fast as it can read and process the input.  No-delay mode would not be expected to improve this -- in fact it might very well make it worse, make it flicker in interactive mode, too, or even break the program altogether  if you don't handle it correctly.

Comment: Would you consider disabling the ncurses UI when input is not from a terminal to be "still using ncurses"?

Comment: Alternatively, you could limit the frequency of screen refreshes, or even the rate of input consumption.

Comment: Did you notice, that the double-pointer `data` is uninitialized? Looks, like it should be initialized with a `NULL` pointer

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings.  Then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  note: other compilers use different options to accomplish the same thing.  The posted code results in numerous messages from the compiler

Comment: OT: regarding `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {`  When the parameters to `main()` are not going to be used, Then use the signature: `int main( void )`  This will also eliminate two of the warnings about unused parameters that the compiler outputs

Comment: OT: regarding this kind of statement: `fprintf(stderr, "error reallocating memory!\n");`  This does not help the user of the application.  Should output both your error message AND the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.  Suggest calling: `perror( "your error message" );`  to properly handle this

Comment: OT: regarding: `if(!(data = realloc(data, (curSize += sizeof(char *))))) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error reallocating memory!\n");
            exit(1);
        }`  This results in a memory leak.  Before calling `exit()`, call `free()` in a loop to un-allocate the input lines, then a final call to `free()` to un-allocate the `data[]` array

Comment: OT: regarding: `static short posX = strlen(SELINDICATOR)`  the function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t`, not a `short int`

Comment: regarding: `nodelay(stdscr, FALSE);`  This results in the program blocking until another character is entered by the user.  Suggest using: `nodelay( stdscr, TRUE );`  so the program does not block, waiting on next character from the user.

Comment: the function: `handleInput())` should NOT be calling: `endwin()` nor `exit(0)`   Suggest moving those calls to the end of `main()`.   The current location means the program will exit before completing this loop:  `while(1) {

        draw(data, index, selected);
        handleInput(&selected, index);
    }`  and if the 'exit()' were not in the function `handleInput()`  then the code would NEVER get out of this loop.

Comment: The variable `selected` is initialized to 1 and never changed, so the posted code will never recognize the 'end of line' so will never move to a new line on the terminal

Comment: @user3629249 I removed some code to make it minimal but couldn't make it perfect and I don't intend to change line automatically.

Comment: @John Toggling ncurses based on input source sounds like a good idea. I'll try and let you know.

Comment: In that case, if you don't already know about it then you'll be interested in [`isatty()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html).

Comment: @John post it as an answer so I can approve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ncurses is designed and built as a tool for providing an *interactive* user interface.  To the extent that it reads input from from the standard input (as opposed to directly from the terminal), it is possible for an ncurses-based program to have its input redirected from a file or pipe, but it's unclear why it would be important to actually display the UI in that case. If doing so causes unwanted visual effects then the easiest mitigation might be to disable the UI in that case.

In the program presented in the question, it appears that displaying the UI is cleanly separated from reading and processing input, and that reading input relies only minimally on ncurses.  It should be very straightforward to modify such a program to enable it to switch between UI and no-UI modes, and my recommendation is that you do so.  To that end, you may find the [`isatty()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) function useful for determining whether the standard input (and / or standard output) is a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The example is missing something, since this function

```
void
handleInput(short *selected, short numOfEntries) {

    int input = getch();

    /* A whole bunch of other stuff........ */

    endwin();
    exit(0);
}
```

will simply exit after running once.  That leaves a lot of possibilities, the most likely being that you're running this program a lot of times, causing it to initialize the screen (and on a lot of terminals, **switching** to/from the *alternate screen*).  That'll flicker every time...

Comment: I just tried to make it functional with minimum changes. I'll edit and attatch the full code once I reach ma place.